# How to remove all of the auto-generated comments in NetBeans

Tags: c++, netbeans

I just downloaded NetBeans 7.4 for C++, and upon creating a new file, I was highly annoyed by all of the comments that NetBeans automatically puts into my code. Here is what it gave me, without having to type anything:

```
/* 
 * File:   main.cpp
 * Author: Dave
 *
 * Created on December 14, 2013, 12:38 PM
 */

#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

/*
 * 
 */
int main(int argc, char** argv) {

   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have not used NetBeans for C++ (rather used it for Java), and i have found that you can hide javadoc and comments.

**Tools** > **Options** > **Editors (General)** > **JavaDoc Comments** checked.

Try something like that :)

Answer (score 1):

For generated files (which are build upon a template) you can change the related template in **Tools > Template**.

In your case unfold the C++ section to see which templates exists. To change one, select the template and click on "open in editor". In the editor you can modify the template for your needs.